# Nodejs countdown when left will do some function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have a web Application and i wanna to add a function.
the function as a table will show inside it some result if the user post a request. and if user not post any thing will show different result when the time left.
I work with nodeJs and ejs as view engine. and mongoose as database

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you want a function to run, if user submits a form. In this case you can use `addEventListener` method. An example code:

```
const form  = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
    /*You can write any code here*/
});
```

2. If you want to see a successful post request, (in other words if the visitor has sent data to node.js and if node.js successfully saved this data inside database), then you can set `res.status(201)` in your node.js file. And then detect 201 from your ejs file and then run your method. You can check this question, if you want a solution with 201: [How to get 201 status when uploading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255112/how-to-get-201-status-when-uploading-a-file/69392665#69392665)